# Would like to create a POST method for my Django API

Tags: json, django, post, django-rest-framework, addition

I would like to create a POST method for my Django project while setting up the API. I have tried creating an override method for create but it gives me an integrityconstrain. I would like to make a post that stored all the field in a tidy JSON. I'm not sure if it's because of manytomanyfield that is causing the problems. Thank you in advances.

```
Models.py
class Results(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    ytid = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    correct_answer = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    incorrect_answers = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), 
    blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}'.format(self.type, self.question, 
self.title, self.ytid, self.correct_answer, self.incorrect_answers)

class Simulation(models.Model):
    sequence = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=False)
    method = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    results = models.ForeignKey(Results, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['sequence']

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.sequence)

class respond_code(models.Model):
    respond_code = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    simulation = models.ManyToManyField(Simulation)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['respond_code']

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.respond_code)

Serializers.py
class ResultsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Results
        fields = 
('type','question','title','ytid','correct_answer','incorrect_answers')

class SimulationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    results = ResultsSerializer(many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Simulation
        fields = ('sequence','method','results')


class respond_codeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    simulation = SimulationSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = respond_code
        fields = ('respond_code', 'simulation')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        simulations_data = validated_data.pop('simulation')
        simulation = Simulation.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for i in simulations_data:
            Simulation.objects.create(simulation=simulation, **i)
            for data in simulations_data:
                Simulation.sequence.add(simulation,**data)
                Simulation.method.add(simulation,**data)
                simulation.save()

        #return Simulation.objects.create(simulation=simulation, **i)
        return simulation
```

I have made an amendment to the serializer.py to this

```
class respond_codeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    simulation = SimulationSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = respond_code
        fields = ('respond_code', 'simulation')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        simulations_data = validated_data.pop('simulation')
        simulation = respond_code.objects.create(**validated_data)
        simulation.save()
        for Simulation in simulations_data:
            #d = dict(i)
            b = 
Simulation.objects.get_or_create(sequence=Simulation['sequence'])
            Simulation.add(b)
            #respond_code.save()
        return simulation
```

Comment: IntegrityError at /api/simulation/
null value in column "sequence" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (34, null, , null).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
class respond_codeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    simulation = SimulationSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = respond_code
        fields = ('respond_code', 'simulation')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        simulations_data = validated_data.pop('simulation')
        instance = super(respons_codeSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        for simulation in simulations_data:
            result_data = simulation.pop('results')
            result, c = Results.objects.get_or_create(**result_data)
            sim, c = Simulation.objects.get_or_create(results=result, **simulation)
            instance.simulation.add(sim)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for the help, I received this error: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'collections.OrderedDict'                By the way what is with the 'c'

Comment: `get_or_create()` method returns a tuple of object and a boolean indicates whether it is created or not. That's what's c.

Comment: TypeError at /api/simulation/
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'collections.OrderedDict'     (this is the error I received)

Comment: I meant entire traceback... just post it in the comments.

Comment: Actually, don't bother. I have edited my answer. Try it again.